# Exact string replacing with preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace

I'm having trouble when i try to replace this string:

```
str1 = "mysql_connect($dbhost.':'.$dbport, $dbusername, $dbuserpass);";
```

with this other string:

```
str2 = "$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbuserpass,"normativa",$dbport);";
```

I tried using this:

```
$text = str_ireplace($str1,$str2,$text);
```

The problem seems to be the . (dot) in the first string. I tried escaping it with "." but had no luck.

Is there any other escaping method for the dot or another php function to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: There are multiple issues here. `str_ireplace` doesn't take a regex. Variables in double quotes will be the value, not the variable. `mysql_` functions arent the same as  the `mysqli` functions.

Comment: The fact that your MySQL connection code is in a string like this is a bit terrifying. Something's horribly wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using double quote mark, which will take each `$` as a variable. 
Try this:

```
$text = str_replace('mysql_connect($dbhost.\':\'.$dbport, $dbusername, $dbuserpass);','$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbuserpass,"normativa",$dbport);', $text);
```

Comment: This one did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Most welcome. 
You can select my answer as selected answer